# Importing products with images

Tags: magento-1.8, import

How can I import a products csv with images as well?

Importing products without images works fine. I have inserted the image on:

```
/media/import/test-2.jpg
```

And on the csv _media_image column:

```
/media/import/test-2.jpg
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use the full path to the file in your import file.
So, all images must be located in `media/import` (can also be in a subfolder of it), and in the import csv write only the relative path to `media/import` and start with a slash.

So in your case you need to put this on the image column.

```
/test-2.jpg
```

If your images are in a subfolder of `media/import`, for example `media/import/something/test.jpg` you need to put in the import csv file this:

```
/something/test.jpg
```

Comment: I've tried the exact same thing and doesn't work.
Here the FTP: http://prntscr.com/37s6zq and here the CSV: http://prntscr.com/37s68c . Also did a reindex and cleared all the cache.

Comment: I am doing the import on System->Import/Export->Import. Maybe I need to do it in "Dataflow - Profiles"?

Comment: I tried it on the Dataflow - Profiles and it works perfectly.